# Creating a table converting from F to C with increments of 3

Tags: java

My task is to write a program that displays a table of 20 temperature conversions from Fahrenheit to Celcius and to increment he value in 3 degrees.

This is what I made
public class FahrenheitToCelsius {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int f = 20; f < 78; f = f+3) {
        System.out.println(f + " degrees Fahrenheit is " + (5/9) * (f-32) + " degrees celsius ");

}
```

}
}

Yet when I print it is keeps saying the degrees is 0 for all of them, do I have my order of operations wrong or something?

Answer (score 0):

You are working with `int` so `(5/9) * (f-32)` evaluates to `0 * (f-32)` because integer maths stays integer and `5/9` as an integer is zero. `5.0/9.0 = 0.55555555` which, when converted to an `int` becomes `0`.

Switch to using `float`.

```
    for (float f = 20; f < 78; f = f + 3) {
        System.out.println(f + " degrees Fahrenheit is " + (5.0 / 9.0) * (f - 32) + " degrees celsius ");
    }
```